# Why doesn't changing my link (a) mark-up work?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am trying to create a theme on Tumblr and it appears I cannot change the colours of my links. Also, `text-decoration:none;` does not seem to work either.

```
a {
    color: #757575:
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: consolas;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
    cursor: url(http://i.imgur.com/xbo9KG1.png) 0 0, auto;
}
```

Here is my full code (HTML & CSS) http://pastebin.com/BLa89pWz and the live preview can be seen here: http://azerty83298323.tumblr.com

When inspecting the element it shows it skips the mark-up because of `a:-webkit-any-link` but I don't know what this is? How can I override it?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like all your links are a child of the `metadata` class. Try targeting links in a more specific way: `.metadata > a { .. }`.

Comment: Try reproducing just this single issue using jsfiddle.net.  That will often help you spot the issue, and at least makes it easy for answers to focus on the relevant issues.

Comment: Have a look at CSS specificity, explained using Star Wars.  http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Comment: @EricJ. that's actually pretty nifty..

Comment: I can't find any attempt at changing the link color neither in the pastebin nor in the live preview. When I add a color to the `a` rule in the live preview using firebug, it applies without problem.

Comment: Wait a minute... .metadata wasn't supposed to wrap all this content at all. I put the HTML underneath the post types, so I don't know how this happened? This is probably what is causing the errors though.

Comment: `.metadata > a { .. }` or other specifics don't seem to work though. Going to read through the posted article.